# Selenium script breaks when doing other activities

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to automate my application.. My applicaton works on IE only.. I dont have much scope for other browser..
but when my scripts are running if i do other activities like reading mails, or update QC in another window.. Those are breaking my scripts (no such element or no such window..) once in a while (mostly out of 10, 2 to 3 times i am facing this issue). But can not make system idle till my scripts are run as i do have other activities after started the script. How to stabilize this?? Any one facing these kind of issues??

Comment: you really need to run a self contained version of the browser/window. i'm not sure if you're doing this for testing or not, but it sounds really happ hazzard the approach that you take. in short, use the selenium testing brwoser ONLY for that function. open a seperate instance of the browser for normal browsing duties

Comment: I am using separate browser instance for other duties.. but still there is less chance of breaking

Comment: @ChanGan It has been a while since you asked but I (hopefully) have supplied a better answer.  Please take a look and if you agree then please accept it.

Comment: i do have limitation on trying your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Running Selenium tests locally using your one and only IE browser does come at the cost of having to not touch your mouse or keyboard during test executions.  A way to get around this is to create one or more virtual machines.  [VirtualBox](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8088-virtualbox-install-windows-10-a.html) from Oracle is a popular choice but there are others.  You need to install an operating system on your new virtual machine and odds are that your existing Windows license is single use.  You can request an additional Microsoft Windows OS license from your IT department or simply buy one yourself for, what? $190?  I have done that when the paper work at my client was unmanageable. My time is worth more than that.

Another alternative is to take advantage of 90 day free licenses from [Microsoft](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/).

Start your test on the virtual machine then change focus back to your desktop to do other work.  I have even added code to the end of test logic to beep when the test completes so that I know when to expand my virtual machine.

**Update**

You should add an antivirus to that virtual machine.  Safety first.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

Selenium does not support and non web-based applications, it only supports web based applications. 
So if you are doing activities like reading mails and update QC in other window, you will not able to find the elements through selenium.

If you are facing some challenges with IE browser. Please refer this link:https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

There are following limitations are given below:
Some limitations of Selenium Automation tool are as follows:

1. It does not support and non web-based applications, it only supports web based applications.
2. Its and open source tool so in case of any technical issues you need to rely on the selenium community forums to get your issue resolved.
3. You need to know at least one of the supported language very well in order to automate your application successfully.
4. No inbuilt reporting capability so you need plugins like JUnit and TestNG for test reports.
5. Lot of challenges with IE browser.